# Is there any way to use the same fixture multiple times in a function with pytest?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest, fixtures, fixture

Like this

```
@pytest.fixture
def myfixture():
   # creates a complex object

def test_compare(myfixture,myfixture):
   #compares
```

Is there a way to know which fixture am I working on?
The generated objects are different

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for factory pattern https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#factories-as-fixtures

Here is SO question about advantages of fixture factories [Why would a pytest factory as fixture be used over a factory function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663326/why-would-a-pytest-factory-as-fixture-be-used-over-a-factory-function)

Answering your question

```
@pytest.fixture
def myfixture():
   def _make_fixture():
       # creates a complex object
   return _make_fixture

def test_compare(myfixture):
    data1 = myfixture()
    data2 = myfixture()
    #compares
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to compare objects returned by fixture? Fixtures are not meant to be so.

As per the documentation,

> The purpose of test fixtures is to provide a fixed baseline upon which tests can reliably and repeatedly execute.

If you want to compare returned objects, just make it as a **function**, not as a fixture.Like.

```
def myfixture():
   # creates a complex object

def test_compare():
   a=myfixture()
   b=myfixture()
   #compare a and b
```